# How Can I Align Button Text From Center

Tags: android, xml, button

In my application I've showing Two buttons .Which text are shown below . How can i align both's text from same line(Center).

Hence clearly, I want to start Button Text "Amiyo" & "Amiyo Biswas" From Same Line (Center)

Here is my XML :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

    >



    <Button          
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="Amiyo"           
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        />

     <Button          
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="Amiyo Biswas"           
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I want like this alignment [image]

Comment: They ARE in center. There is difference due to text length.

Comment: Yes . i understand . Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Solve what? There is nothing to solve.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya,I think you trying show "Biswas" text in Second Line in second Button is it ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana No No .

Comment: as MysticMagic said because of text length starting point of both the buttons differes so Try setting the **padding to both the buttons** (Text starting point android:paddingLeft="50dp" ) and text alignment to left

Comment: @Shivaraj2 I am agree with your logic . If i set padding then it shows ok in "MOTO E" but different in "galaxy s5"

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya,can you please put some image as per your requirement ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana I update this

Comment: May be you can try giving fix margin before text based on device width's calculation

Comment: @MysticMagic Sir :I think so

Comment: I have never seen a text-only button where the text is not aligned to the middle. It's going to look ugly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the button texts to be aligned with each other. The below does that by only centering vertically. The horizontal alignment is to the left and I've added some padding so it still looks kinda horizontally centered.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="Amiyo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="120dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:text="Amiyo Biswas"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="120dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Note that setting the padding manually to make it look horizontally centered will only work on one screen size. If you run it on a different device with a different screen width it will look wrong again. To fix that you would have to do some calculations in code and set the padding programmatically. But at that point I would give up and just set it left aligned. Or start learning about writing widgets yourself and solve this properly, but that would take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First set the text alignment to left|center_vertical and then set the left padding of text

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:text="Button 1" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:text="Button 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code like this..I  tried and this works (two buttons on same line also centered)

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:text="Amiyo" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Amiyo Biswas" />

</LinearLayout>
```

copy this in xml file ......

Try to use Listview :- 
refer this link:- (http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)

```
     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
     </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind attentions . I use android:layout_width="fill_parent" instead of wrap_content

Comment: In my opinion you can use Listview                                 you can refer this link :-http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here i play with weight so is might be fit your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ONE MILE"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIVE MILES"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEN MILES"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is a hardcoded and you can try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


 <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button1"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:text="Amiyo"  />         

 <Button          
   android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingLeft="105dp" 
    android:text="Amiyo Biswas"  />       

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I trying to avoid hard-coded value . Probably i need custom class